# lwuit text area

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I developed an RSS Application for two XML files and displayed it on two LWUIT Tabs. The problem is with my LWUIT TextArea, whenever I click on my ListForm (it contains titles from the RssFile), I need to display description information from the RSS File.  First time I am able to display the description related to the title clicked in ListForm.  If I click the ListForm the next time onwards I am able to display the same description again and again in the textarea..(Eventhough I am getting Related Description from RssFile)

Here is my Code:

```
        private void displayCompleteNewsScreen(News detailNews) {

        Label title = new Label(detailNews.getTitle()); 
        form2.setTitleComponent(title);
        String Description = detailNews.getDescription();
        System.out.println("Description" + Description);//Here i am able to get different Description values Related to myList Screen but in text area it is displaying First one always
        big = new TextArea();

        big.setEditable(false);
        big.setText(Description);

        form2.addComponent(pubDate);
        form2.addComponent(big);
        form2.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are reusing `form2` instance you should clear it in `displayCompleteNewsScreen` method. Call `removeAll` before calling `setTitleComponent`.

And don't forget to set `form2` `Command`s again in `displayCompleteNewsScreen`.